# changing the href of anchor inside ajax return but then it is overwritten

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello all i have a problem i have a table with a link in one of the columns 
on the click of that link i send it to a function that uses ajax to get a different link for it to direct to.
inside the ajax function it is being changed correctly but then after it finishes the ajax it still redirects to the original page.
if i change it outside of the ajax return it works correctly and redirects to a different site

this is my code:

the php function for building the table

```
function populate()
{
$link = connectToDB();
$query = 'Select value1, value2
         from table1';
$data = read($query, $link);
$table = '<div id="table"><table id="links">
            <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>   
          </tr>';

$num =0;
while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $row['value1'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td><a id="redirection'.$num.'" onclick="redirect('.$num.')" href=”/?redirection.php?' . $row['value2'] . '>' . $row['value1'] .'</td>';
    $table .= '</tr>';
    $num++;
}
$table .= '</table></div>';
mysqli_close($link);
return $table;
}
```

the javascript to change the href

```
function redirect(num){
    var url = $("#redirection"+num).attr("href");
    var sub = url.split('?');
    var val1= sub[2];
    var test = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getNewUrl.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: val1},
        success: function(table){
            alert(table.val2);
            $("#redirection"+num).attr("href",table.val2);
            var check =$("#redirection"+num);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("No value with that name");
        }
    });
}
```

when i am alerting the value retured it is the correct one, and when i am checking the href value of check in debugger it is being changed correctly but then i am still redirected to the wrong site

thanks for the help

Comment: did you checkout your console logs ?

Comment: Try checking if the `href` of the link has changed in the chrome inspector. Also try to console log the `check` inside the success callback, to see if an element was found matching `$('#redirection' + num)`

Comment: Hi i did that also when i inspect the check variable after it is assigned i can see that it's href is set correctly
The problem is that when i leave the scope of the ajax it is being changed to the original link again

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in `href=”/?` and wrong doublequote and miss close quote and remove `"?"` after `=/`

```
onclick="redirect('.$num.')" href=”/?redirection.php?' . $row['value2'] . '
```

it's sould be like this.

```
onclick="redirect('.$num.')" href="/redirection.php?' . $row['value2'] .'"
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i was using a wrong doublequotes so the original link wasnt good either i fixed that but it didnt really help
it is still being changed correctly inside th scope of the ajax and then going back to original once i leave that scope

Comment: what is val2 on function redirect ? and what you try to do? just change the atributte href or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i as going about this all wrong and just figured it out
instead of changing the href and then having it redirect me to a page 
i just used 
window.location
to redirect me from inside the ajax
and the href change was redundent

Thanks to all who tried to help me